# Порядок вывода сообщений

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Есть список, хотелось бы в панели администрирования менять позицию отображения. То есть в базе есть колонка `position`, в ней указано текущее положение текста. Видимо реализация на JavaScript или на JQuery. Видел подобное, по-моему, в e107, когда позицию вывода можно менять "на лету" или, к примеру, в ВК можно менять фотографии местами аналогично "на лету". Вопрос: как это сделать?
Список выводится соответственно циклом из базы.

Comment: а как это делалось раньше?? ведь раньше не было JQuery???

Answer (score 1):

Самый быстрый способ это вставить спрятанные инпуты внутрь блоков и после их перетягивания вызывать функцию которая проходилась бы по ним и записывала значение позиции, примерно вот так

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        start:function(){ return sortNumber = 1;},
        stop: function(){
            $('li input').each(function(){
                $(this).val(sortNumber);
                sortNumber++;
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Когда функция стартует создаем переменную, которая будет записываться в инпуты и в каждой итерации увеличиваем ее на один. Вот хтмл код блока

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1<input class="hidden" type="text" name="pos1" value="" /></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2<input class="hidden" type="text" name="pos2" value="" /></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3<input class="hidden" type="text" name="pos3" value="" /></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Отправляем все это на сервер и записываем в базу значения.

Comment: функция на js или на jquery?

Comment: для функции перетягивания используется jqueyui, которые работают вместе с jquery, поэтому сама функция которая записывает значения в инпуты на jquery

Answer (score 0):

http://wil-linssen.com/entry/jquery-sortable-lists-with-drag-drop-handle/ насколько я понял